# Merging many tables with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

where should I put conditions to separate users based on 'Role'?

this is my fiddle 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rcsGy77aooBJFfXnvdi6K1/0

My last results is like this

[image]

I want to add more columns based on 'roles'. maybe it will be like this

```
dinas_id | dinas_nama | total_user(Admin) | total_user(Kontraktor) | total_user(Pptk) | total_user(Bidang) | total_user(Konsultan) | total_user(Dll) | total_user(Owner) | total_bidang | total_kegiatan | total_paket
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this is what you looking for

```
SELECT dinas.dinas_id,
   dinas_nama,
   (select count(*) from sc_user where role='Admin' and dinas_id = dinas.dinas_id) as 'total_user(Admin)',
   (select count(*) from sc_user where role='Kontraktor' and dinas_id = dinas.dinas_id) as 'total_user(Kontraktor)',
   (select count(*) from sc_user where role='Pptk' and dinas_id = dinas.dinas_id) as 'total_user(Pptk)',
   (select count(*) from sc_user where role='Bidang' and dinas_id = dinas.dinas_id) as 'total_user(Bidang)',
   (select count(*) from sc_user where role='Konsultan' and dinas_id = dinas.dinas_id) as 'total_user(Konsultan)',
   (select count(*) from sc_user where role='Dll' and dinas_id = dinas.dinas_id) as 'total_user(Dll)',
   (select count(*) from sc_user where role='Owner' and dinas_id = dinas.dinas_id) as 'total_user(Owner)',
   COUNT(DISTINCT sc_bidang.bi_id) as total_bidang,
   COUNT(DISTINCT sc_kegiatan.ke_id) as total_kegiatan,
   COUNT(DISTINCT sc_kegiatan.ke_id, sc_paket.pa_id) as total_paket
FROM dinas
LEFT JOIN sc_user on dinas.dinas_id=sc_user.dinas_id
LEFT JOIN sc_bidang on dinas.dinas_id=sc_bidang.dinas_id
LEFT JOIN sc_kegiatan on dinas.dinas_id=sc_kegiatan.dinas_id
LEFT JOIN sc_paket on sc_paket.ke_id=sc_kegiatan.ke_id
GROUP by dinas.dinas_id
```